# CakePHP Show Validation Message on Hidden Field

Tags: forms, validation, cakephp

In my form I've created a hidden field:

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('editor_rating', array('value' => 0));
```

Which outputs:

In my model I've created a validation rule:

```
'editor_rating' => array(
                    'rule'    => array('comparison', 'greater or equal', 1),
                    'message' => 'Please choose a valid Editor Rating'
    )
```

When I submit the form the hidden field has an error class added, but no visible change and no error message:

```
<input id="ListingEditorRating" class="form-error" type="hidden" value="0" name="data[Listing][editor_rating]">
```

How can I make this error message visible or even attach it to a different div?

Comment: Why would you make a hidden field if you want it (and the validation error) to be displayed? Doesnt make sense to me. Use a normal field. Especially with validation - or how you would expect a user to "chose a valid rating"? The form will never be able to validate without the option to select a different value.

Comment: The value of the hidden field is set with javascript using bootstrap button styles. I don't want to make the hidden field visible, only the error message.

Answer (score 3):

### FormHelper::error

For use cases where `Form->input` or `Form->inputs` are not used you can [render errors explicitly](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#FormHelper::isFieldError):

```
if ($this->Form->isFieldError('gender')) {
    echo $this->Form->error('gender');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so it doesn't look like there is any built in method to handle what I need which is understandable, so I'm handling it manually by checking the validationErrors for the field.

Here is a cleaner example than the editor_rating field I used perviously:

(artist_picker uses jQuery autocomplete to fetch a list of matching artists. We want to display the artist name in the input, but need to submit the artist_id to the DB, hence updating the hidden field)

```
echo $this->Form->hidden('artist_id', array('div' => false));

echo $this->Form->input('artist_picker', array(
                'label'=> false,
                'div'=> (isset($this->validationErrors['Listing']['artist_id']) ? 'span4 error' : 'span4'), // Turn on error class if errors
                'class' => (isset($this->validationErrors['Listing']['artist_id']) ? 'span12 form-error' : 'span12'), // Turn on form-error class if errors
                'after' => (isset($this->validationErrors['Listing']['artist_id']) ? '<div class="error-message">'.$this->validationErrors['Listing']['artist_id'][0].'</div>' : ''),
                'type'=>'text') // Show error message if errors 
                );
```

Comment: You could instead use a normal input and simply style it as `display:none` (if you're using bootstrap by adding the class `hide`).

Comment: The comment by @AD7six is the right answer. You could also set `label=""` to get rid of the label.